# how it return the boolean result?

Tags: c++, function

```html
class Solution
{
public:
  bool isPowerOfThree (int n)
  {
    double temp = log10 (n) / log10 (3);
      return !(temp - (int) temp);

  }
};
```

in the leetcode problem 326:Power of Three
Given an integer, write a function to determine if it is a power of three.

I don't understand how it returns the boolean result.

I expect someone can tell me how to understand this following code: `return ! (temp - (int) temp);`

Comment: As you allow `int` as input: logarithms aren't defined for values <= 0! So you need special handling for.

Comment: Another special case: What is the logarithm of 1???

Answer (score 1):

`temp` is a `double`, and `(int)temp` truncates it to an `int`. Let's say temp is `1.5`,  `temp - (int)temp` is `0.5`. since the return type is `bool` the function will cast the resulting `0.5` to a `bool` `!(0.5)` which should be `false`.

Words from @Nautatava "everything except `!(0)`, `!(false)` and `!(null)` gives false. Thus `!(anything other than 0)` is `false`."

Comment: Adding to the explanation, everything except !(0), !(false) and !(null) gives false. Thus !(anything other than 0) is false.

Answer (score 1):

The solution relies on `temp` being a whole number when `n` is some power of `3` and `temp` being a number with some fractional value when `n` is not a power of `3`.

Let's say `n` is `9`.
Then, `temp` will be `2.0`.
Then, `(temp-(int)temp)` will be `0` and `!(temp-(int)temp)` will be `true`.

Let's say `n` is `10`.
Then, `temp` will be `2.0959`.
Then, `(temp-(int)temp)` will be `0.0959` and `!(temp-(int)temp)` will be `false`.

Unfortunately, floating point computations are not that precise. It will be better to use:

```
double temp = log10 (n) / log10 (3);
double diff = (temp - (int) temp);`
return (std::abs(diff) < tolerance);
```

where `tolerance` can be a small number, such as `1.0E-6`.

#### Update

My experiment with cygwin/g++ on my computer and at ideone.com suggests that the tolerance can be `1.0e-6` for a large set of numbers but it needs to be almost `1.0e-11` or smaller for INT_MAX. See https://ideone.com/BgnQxV.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, any idea which would be the largest epsilon that fits all values in between 1 and INT_MAX? As `log(n)` grows boundlessly (correct term in English?), but `log(n+1)-log(n)` goes against 0 for `n` going against infinity, we'd find a sufficiently large n for *any* epsilon to make the test fail, solely that this n will be too large to fit in integer range if epsilon is small enough...

Comment: Experimented a bit, 1.0e-6 indeed is too large, try with 4782970...

Comment: @Aconcagua, my experiment with cygwin/g++ suggests that it can be 1.0e-6 for a large set of numbers but it needs to be almost 1.0e-11 for INT_MAX. https://ideone.com/BgnQxV.

Comment: Tried with negative powers of two, managed to find numbers for 2^-30 (32-bit signed integers) and 2^31 (32-bit unsigned integers). Looks suspiciously as if we'd need 2^-n to be safe for positive n-bit values, not trying to prove mathematically, though...

Answer (score 0):

This code is simply using integer truncation to test whether the number `temp` is a whole number.  If it is, then `temp - (int)temp` will be zero.  Since that would then mean the number is a power of three, then the unary "not" operator `!` will return true.  And of course `!` used on any non-zero (true) value will be false.